# Take Scanner input from string, not from System.in

Tags: java

So I have to take in a list of numbers on one line and print out the max and min values (without using arrays or anything).

I have it working with JOptionPane but I'd rather not use that too much. Having trouble doing it with just a scanner. Basically I need the Scanner to take its input from a string but everything I've tried hasn't worked (including establishing a new Scanner).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class minMaxNum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers sperated by spaces:");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);

    double minNum;
    double maxNum;
    
    if (numbers.hasNextDouble()) {
        minNum = reader.nextDouble();
        maxNum = minNum;
        
        while (numbers.hasNextDouble()) {
            double currentNum = numbers.nextDouble();
            if (currentNum < minNum) {
                minNum = currentNum;
            } else if (currentNum > maxNum) {
                maxNum = currentNum;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Range: " + (int)minNum + " => " + (int)maxNum);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So to clarify, you want to scan a string and use basic Scanner methods on the string?

Comment: `input` is already a string. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Yes @JacobB. Basically for error checking. (and the scanner should have been called numbers, forgot to change that before copy/pasting)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with a 'space' as the delimiter and then convert each word to a number

```
for (String str : input.split(" ")) {
    Douibe currentNum = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code: (This works the way you asked)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class minMaxNum {

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers sperated by spaces:");
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(input);

    double minNum;
    double maxNum;

    if (numbers.hasNextDouble()) {
        minNum = numbers.nextDouble();
        maxNum = minNum;

        while (numbers.hasNextDouble()) {
            double currentNum = numbers.nextDouble();
            if (currentNum < minNum) {
                minNum = currentNum;
            } else if (currentNum > maxNum) {
                maxNum = currentNum;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Range: " + (int)minNum + " => " + (int)maxNum);
    }
}
```